# Why is the integral value on complex domain?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

$B_n=\{z \in C^n : |z|<1\}$ $,\quad$ $dv$ is volume measure on $B_n$

$\displaystyle \int_{B_n}z^{\alpha}\bar z^{\beta} dv(z)=0\;(?)$ when $\alpha \neq \beta$

how to prove it.

i learned multiple integral, so $\displaystyle \int \displaystyle \int_{D} f(z)dA=\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} f(z)dxdy$ style solution please...

Comment: Are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ integers?

Comment: yes, i think that using polar coordinate, i want to detail solution

Comment: Perhaps $\alpha,\beta$ are multi-indices.  So $z \in \mathbb C^n$ has the form $z = (z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n)$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb N^n$ has the form $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n)$ so that $z^\alpha$ means $z_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots z_n^{\alpha_n}$.  Only josha can tell us.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to show that the intergal w.r.t. $j-$th coordinate is $0$ where $j$ is chosen such that $\alpha _j \neq \beta_j$.  In other words the proof reduced to one-dimensaional case. So let $n=1$.

Write $z=re^{i\theta} $ with $r \geq 0, 0<\theta \leq 2\pi$ and note that the given integral becomes $\int_0^{1}\int_0^{2\pi} r^{\alpha} e^{i\alpha \theta} r^{\beta} e^{-i\beta \theta} d\theta dr$ and the inside integral is $e^{i(\alpha -\beta)\theta}|_0^{2\pi}$ which is zero if $\alpha \neq \beta$.

Comment: B_n is n-dimension, so how to express?

Comment: @joshe111 I have edited the answer.

Comment: although it is n-th complex plane, using 1-dimension. ok got it. thanks